# Recursive Definitions - Should I use logic notation (i.e. arrows or "for n =...")

Tags: recursive-algorithms

[b.] $a_n = 1 + (-1)^n $

\begin{align*}
a_1 = 1 + (-1)^1 = 0\\
a_2 = 1 + (-1)^2 = 2\\
a_3 = 1 + (-1)^3 = 0\\
a_4 = 1 + (-1)^4 = 2\\
\vdots
\\ \\
\text{Recurisve Definition: }\\
a_1 = 0 \\
a_n = 2 \text{ for } a_{n-1} = 0 \\
a_n = 0 \text{ for } a_{n-1} = 2 \\
\end{align*}

Should it be like that ^

Or like this:
\begin{align*}
\text{Recurisve Definition: }\\
a_1 = 0 \\
a_{n-1} = 0 \rightarrow a_n = 2  \\
a_{n-1} = 2 \rightarrow a_n = 0 \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any of those is really standard.  One thing you might write is:

$$ \begin{align*}
a_1 & = 0 \\
a_n & = \begin{cases}
2,&\text{when $a_{n-1} = 0$} \\
0,&\text{when $a_{n-1} = 2$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

But more likely:

$$ \begin{align*}
a_1 & = 0 \\
a_n & = a_{n-1} + 2\cdot(-1)^n & (n>1)
\end{align*}$$

But it's a little hard to say because the problem is so contrived. Who needs a recursive definition of $a_n = 1 + (-1)^n$ ?

Comment: haha thanks, yeah it's for an intro to discrete math class so it's just to practice writing recursive definitions